# Handling of periodic heart-beat messages from BT chip

Tags: java, android, multithreading

Am very new to java and I have a task to implement a heartbeat mechanism to monitor the aliveness of BT chip.

The BT chip keeps sending an empty message (only message ID and no content) over the uart interface every 5s which has to be read by the java module.  If the message is not received, then the assumption is that the firmware on the chip is dead and it needs a reset and java module can do that by toggling a GPIO.

The module responsible for the read from uart is implemented as class extending a thread. I tried using android.os.CountdownTimer, but it doesn't work.  It throws this error:

**AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()**

What's the best mechanism in java to use to implement such a requirement?

```
/*Start timer for 5s for receiving heartbeat*/
mTimer=new CountDownTimer(5000,1000) {
    @Override
    public void onTick ( long l){
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish () {
        Log.e(TAG, "Nothing received for 5s, missed heartbeat, reset BT chip");
        try {
            resetBTChip(false);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Can't reset the chip");
            return;
        }
    }
};

mTimer.start();

/*Check the message and deal with timer*/
if(HEART_BEAT.getCode()==opcode) {
    mTimer.cancel(); /*Restart the timer on heart-beat event*/
    mTimer.start();
    Log.e(TAG, "Got HEART BEAT");
    continue;
} else {
    Log.e(TAG, "Got Something else, handle the message");
    mTimer.cancel(); /*Restart the timer on any event*/
    mTimer.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do a runnable and a handler.  Handlers have a postdelay function that allows you to specify how long to wait before running the runnable.  They also have the ability to delete/cancel the timer.  That's the way I've done the heartbeat before.  You could try that if the countdown isn't working out.

So the runnable would be in charge of the reset function.  You'd use your current timer.  And if you get a heartbeat again, you just cancel the current runnable, and add it back in with the postdelay function to restart the timer.